# Calculo de frete com WS correios via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-service, cross-domain

Estou tentando fazer o calculo do frete dos correios via javascript, porem quando faço o teste não puxa os dados e me retorna o erro

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx/CalcPrecoPrazo?nCd…&nVlDiametro=0&sCdMaoPropria=s&nVlValorDeclarado=200&sCdAvisoRecebimento=s. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Segue abaixo a função em js que estou usando.

```
function calcWsCorreios{
var sendjson = {   
"nCdEmpresa":"",
"sDsSenha":"",
"nCdServico":"41106",
"sCepOrigem":"37540000",
"sCepDestino":"37540000",
"nVlPeso":"1",
"nCdFormato":"1",
"nVlComprimento":"20",
"nVlAltura":"5",
"nVlLargura":"15",
"nVlDiametro":"0",
"sCdMaoPropria":"s",
"nVlValorDeclarado":"200",
"sCdAvisoRecebimento":"s"
}



$.ajax({
type: "GET",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url:
"http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx/CalcPrecoPrazo",
data: sendjson,
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function (data,err) {

        console.log(data);
        console.log(err);
    },
});

}
```

Se mudo o dataType para  "jsonp" ele me retorna o xml porem não sei como poderia pegar essa informação:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

[image: imagem com o erro e dados retornados]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Access-Control-Allow-Origin jQuery Ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298003/access-control-allow-origin-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score -2):

Ao invés de `success`, utilize `jsonpCallback`. E ao invés de passar uma função, informe o nome dela.

Assim:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx/CalcPrecoPrazo",
    data: sendjson,
    dataType: "jsonp"
    jsonpCallback: "foo"
}

function foo (resultado) {
    // verifique que resultado é JSON válido
    console.log(resultado);
}
```

Comment: Assim da o mesmo erro da imagem. Porque o retorno do web service é em  xml.

Comment: Resolveu, @Shikaizi? Estou com mesmo problema

Comment: Infelizmente não. No final acabei não precisando usar o WS dos correios mais!