# Access-Control-Allow-Origin jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando acessar a api dos correios para calcular frete e recebo a seguinte msg:

```
Failed to load 
http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx/CalcPrecoPrazo: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://site.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

meu ajax:

```
          var params = {
                'nCdEmpresa': '',
                'sDsSenha': '',
                'nCdServico': '04014',
                'sCepOrigem': '03638010',
                'sCepDestino': '43810040',
                'nVlPeso': '1',
                'nCdFormato': '1',
                'nVlComprimento': '16',
                'nVlAltura': '5',
                'nVlLargura': '15',
                'nVlDiametro': '0',
                'sCdMaoPropria': 'n',
                'nVlValorDeclarado': '0',
                'sCdAvisoRecebimento': 'n',
                'StrRetorno': 'xml',
                'nCdServico': '40010,41106'
            };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx/CalcPrecoPrazo",
            data: params,
            dataType : "xml",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
```

Comment: O navegador bloqueia devido [**cors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS), para fazer funcionar é necessário uma gambiarra (proxy reverso)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr como fazer o ajax com proxy reverso ?

Comment: Depende do seu servidor. Caso seja *Nginx*: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Você é o dono da API que está consumindo? Para liberar o CORS, deve-se ter acesso ao "back-end" da API.

Comment: Acho que este link te vai ajudar um bocado https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ajax/#cors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se é impossível, mas você consegue acessar a API dos Correios ao lado do servidor. Se estiver utilizando PHP crie um arquivo, exemplo: *calcula_frete.php*

```php
/* Recupere os dados enviados via POST
 * Documentação: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input-array.php
 */
$DADOS = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
/* Utilize a função 'http_build_query' para construir a string de consulta
 * Documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-build-query.php
 * 
 * Utilize a função 'simplexml_load_file' para carregar os dados da API
 * Documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-file.php
 */
$resultado = simplexml_load_file( 'http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.aspx?' . http_build_query($DADOS) );
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Depois basta fazer a requisição:

```html
<h2>Frete:</h2>
<div id="frete"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var params = {
            'nCdEmpresa': '',
            'sDsSenha': '',
            'nCdServico': '40010,41106',
            'sCepOrigem': '03638010',
            'sCepDestino': '43810040',
            'nVlPeso': '1',
            'nCdFormato': '1',
            'nVlComprimento': '16',
            'nVlAltura': '5',
            'nVlLargura': '15',
            'nVlDiametro': '0',
            'sCdMaoPropria': 'n',
            'nVlValorDeclarado': '0',
            'sCdAvisoRecebimento': 'n',
            'StrRetorno': 'xml',
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calcula_frete.php",
            data: params,
            success: function(data) {
                var j = JSON.parse(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < j.cServico.length; i++) {
                    $('#frete').append(' \
<div>Código: <b>' + j.cServico[i].Codigo + '</b></div> \
<div>Valor: <b>' + j.cServico[i].Valor + '</b></div> \
<div>Prazo entrega: <b>' + j.cServico[i].PrazoEntrega + '</b></div><br>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### Referências

- [`filter_input_array`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input-array.php)
- [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-build-query.php)
- [`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Comment: boa, vou tentar!

Answer (score -3):

Se eu entendi direito você está fazendo um XMLHttpRequest para um domínio diferente do que sua página está (Correios). Portanto, o navegador está bloqueando isso, pois normalmente permite uma solicitação na mesma origem por motivos de segurança. Você precisa fazer algo diferente quando quiser fazer uma solicitação entre domínios usando o CORS.

Páginas web regulares podem usar o objeto XMLHttpRequest para enviar e receber dados de servidores remotos, mas eles são limitados pela mesma política de origem. Extensões não são tão limitadas. Uma extensão pode falar com servidores remotos fora de sua origem, desde que primeiro solicite permissões de origem cruzada.

Incremente seu código Ajax:

```
<script>
  var params = {
                'nCdEmpresa': '',
                'sDsSenha': '',
                'nCdServico': '04014',
                'sCepOrigem': '03638010',
                'sCepDestino': '43810040',
                'nVlPeso': '1',
                'nCdFormato': '1',
                'nVlComprimento': '16',
                'nVlAltura': '5',
                'nVlLargura': '15',
                'nVlDiametro': '0',
                'sCdMaoPropria': 'n',
                'nVlValorDeclarado': '0',
                'sCdAvisoRecebimento': 'n',
                'StrRetorno': 'xml',
                'nCdServico': '40010,41106'
            };

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx/CalcPrecoPrazo',
    data: params,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
    beforeSend: setHeader
});
</script>
```

Se for o que entendi, desse modo deve funcionar.

Comment: O que é `setHeader` ?

Comment: São os cabeçalhos html definidos pelo desenvolvedor, por exemplo, beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
        }

Comment: Você define o header html por estar usando Jquery, por exemplo se for definir os header em PHP, você usarioa header("Content-Type:application/json");

Comment: em type, define post se o service dos correios aceitarem apenas o método post, e quanto ao beforeSend, é o que deve ser executado após o envio da sua requisição, sendo ela opcional.